# getting error with d3 (V4) Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: d3.js

Getting error while creating Stacked Bar Chart using D3 JS in a Angular 2 application,

here is the code,

```
 //data
    var data = [
        { month: 'Jan', A: 20, B: 5, C: 10 },
        { month: 'Feb', A: 30, B: 10, C: 20 }
    ];


    var xData = ["A", "B", "C"];

    var margin = { top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 0 },
        width = 350 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scaleBand()
        .range([0, width])
        .padding(0.35);

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);

    var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


    var dataIntermediate = xData.map(function (c) {
        return data.map(function (d) {
            return { x: d.month, y: d[c] };
        });
    });

    var dataStackLayout = d3.stack().keys([dataIntermediate]);

    x.domain(dataStackLayout[0].map(function (d) {
        return d.x;
    }));

    y.domain([0,
        d3.max(dataStackLayout[dataStackLayout.length - 1],
            function (d) { return d.y0 + d.y; })
    ])
        .nice();

    var layer = svg.selectAll(".stack")
        .data(dataStackLayout)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "stack")
        .style("fill", function (d, i) {
            return color(i);
        });

    layer.selectAll("rect")
        .data(function (d) {
            return d;
        })
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("x", function (d) {
            return x(d.x);
        })
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return y(d.y + d.y0);
        })
        .attr("height", function (d) {
            return y(d.y0) - y(d.y + d.y0);
        })
        .attr("width", x.range());

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);
```

Error are,

1. (51,41): error TS7017: Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type.

@ below line,
    return { x: d.month, y: d[c] };

2. (76,19): error TS2345: Argument of type '(this: BaseType, d: {}) => {}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValueFn'.
   Type '{}' is not assignable to type '{}[]'.
    Property 'find' is missing in type '{}'.

@ below line,
    var dataStackLayout = d3.stack().keys([dataIntermediate]);

Comment: Hello. I tried reworking your code but i also reworked the official Stacked Bar Chart example made by Mike. Check these github files: https://github.com/bluePlayer/practices/tree/master/D3js%20Exercises/StackedBarChart https://github.com/bluePlayer/practices/tree/master/D3js%20Exercises/StackedBarChartError and http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208

Comment: I am also learning D3js so its kind of hard to me to understand how D3js stack works. But I can see one bad bug in your code and that is: d3.stack() creates new d3 stack structure and you cannot use it as data afterwards. But you can do var series = d3.stack().keys(["A", "B", "C"]);

Comment: Also consult the API reference for stack: https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#stack

Answer (score 0):

im using same example to implement stacked barchart in angular2.
i think your issue is

`var dataStackLayout = d3.stack().keys([dataIntermediate]);`

dataStackedLayout should be `array` instead of `function`.

were you able to resolve this issue yet?